# 3rd texture coordinate in Wavefront *.OBJ file

Tags: opengl, format, coordinates, textures, wavefront

What is the meaning of 3rd component in texture coords in Wavefront *.OBJ file ?

File looks like

```
vt 0.8490 0.1109 -0.2498
vt 0.8580 0.1235 -0.2498
vt 0.8695 0.1338 -0.2498
vt 0.8828 0.1416 -0.2498
vt 0.9135 0.1474 -0.2360
vt 0.8981 0.1457 -0.2360
vt 0.8835 0.1409 -0.2360
```

---

UPDATE
Model was created in 3DS Max and source texture was PNG file. So texture is 2D

---

UPDATE 2

When I flip second coordinate then texture looks properly when I render it with OpenGL.
3rd coordinate

u1 = u
v1 = 1 - v

w - is not used at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd coordinate should be ignored. Only first 2 are used to map texture.

Answer (score 2):

The model is apparently using a volume texture.

Comment: What is volume texture? Model is created in 3DS Max and it has texture as PNG file. Source texture is 2D.

Comment: Not neccessarily a volume texture. Especially 3DS Max tends to put out 3D texCoords even for simple 2D mappings, depending on the UVW generation mode I guess.

Answer (score 0):

vt specify the fact that the coordonates are texture coordonates.

Read more about the Wavefront .obj format.
http://www.fileformat.info/format/wavefrontobj/egff.htm